# file location from IO::File

Tags: perl

[IO::File->new_tmpfile](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::File) returns IO::File object which points to file. Is it possible to get file location on Windows?

Comment: Don't you have to specify the file path when calling Open?

Comment: In general, the tmp file may not even have a name (on Unix, it gets unlinked immediately after being opened).  Are you sure the same is not true for Windows?

Comment: Nemo: Windows works differently.

Comment: jp2code: new_tmpfile is a constructor

Comment: Why can't you use File::Temp?

Comment: runrig: I was investigating a bug report for IO::File->new_tmpfile, but I just tested it other way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this with [File::Temp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aTemp):

```
my $fh = File::Temp->new();
my $fname = $fh->filename;
```

In case of IO::File, getting temp file name doesn't look possible. Source of IO::File shows that only OutputStream is stored in the object:

```
void
new_tmpfile(packname = "IO::File")
    const char * packname
    PREINIT:
    OutputStream fp; ## it doesn't look like you can get file name out of this
    GV *gv;
    CODE:
#ifdef PerlIO
    fp = PerlIO_tmpfile();
#else
    fp = tmpfile();
#endif
    ...
```

As far as I know not all streams have file name associated with it (for example pipes).

Comment: In my case, I need it for IO::File

Comment: @Alexandr This is not possible unless you know how to extract file name out of the stream. See my update.